# Pygithub g.get_repo() working in local but not on github hosted and self hosted runners

Tags: ubuntu, github, github-actions, pygithub, github-actions-runners

I have a code which is working fine in my local but not on github actions.

```
token = "some-token"
repo_name = "customer-sandbox/some-repo"  # org/repo format
g = Github(token)
repo = g.get_repo(repo_name)
print(repo)
```

On github and self hosted runners, it is giving me this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/runner/work/somerepo-issueops/somerepo-issueops/replace_variables_in_pull_requests.py", line 18, in 
> repo = g.get_repo(repo_name)
> File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/github/MainClass.py", line 321, in get_repo
> headers, data = self.__requester.requestJsonAndCheck("GET", url)
> File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 398, in requestJsonAndCheck
> return self.__check(
> File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 423, in __check
> raise self.__createException(status, responseHeaders, output)
> github.GithubException.GithubException: 404 {"data": "Not Found"}
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I tested with same token and repos on local and on github actions. Still same error

Comment: How are you passing token in github actions?  and how is your script reading token?

Comment: I had issue with token permissions. I updated it in the workflow. It worked.